# Fetch Data From Modular Form On Close

Tags: c#, winforms, modular

I am creating a modular form in C#, and would like to know how to retrieve the data from the modular form upon closing for usage on the main form?

Comment: how are you showing the form?

Comment: @Sayse what do you mean? From the main form I instantiate the modular form and display it using ShowDialog().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using `ShowDialog` you can use a `using` block. If you set the DialogResult on close as well, you can make sure you only use these details if closed correctly

```
//OnClosing...
DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

using(var myFormInstance = new myForm())
{

    myFormInstance.ShowDialog()  //<-- Only if you dont need to check dlg result
    //whilst in here myFormInstance will give me access to the variables
    if(myFormInstance.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //<-If you do check result
    {
       //success
    }
}
```

Just provide public methods or properties to values that you wish to retrieve and then call them and use them accordingly

Comment: No, that should be inside your "modular form" it has an OnClosing event ([like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onclosing(v=vs.110).aspx)), but then you may have a button that closes the form, wherever you close the form, add the `DialogResult` line above it. Note that you do not have to use this, its just a suggestion to make sure you don't use values when your user clicked a cancel button for example.

Comment: Gotcha. Another question, whenever I try to use the using block, the compiler complains that the type must be implicitly convertible to an IDisposable object. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: @AlanW - Appologies I may have my example slightly skewed.. I'll edit